# Where is the bluez c api documentation

Tags: c, linux, bluez

I want to use the `bluetooth/bluetooth.h` but I can't find any official resources for it.
What's the right approach to look up for function description and so on for this topic?

Comment: You should have posted a more detailed question proposing your implemementation.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main API for Bluez: The lower-level Bluetooth Management API and the higher-level D-Bus API.

They are all documented at:  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

Comment: Thanks, obviously i have no clue about how to work with this. So where i can find for example the hci_get_route() funktion

Comment: My understanding is, that command is from a deprecated API. 
Typically people are pointed towards the code for the bluetootctl client as an example: 
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/client

Comment: So... the client gatt.c has 3175 lines, and *two* (unnecessary) comments in it. Classy. I think I might be looking elsewhere for examples.

Comment: BlueZ documentation is atrocious. Especially for C programmers.